# Well-posed vs Well-conditioned

Tags: terminology, definition

What's the difference between a well-posed (ill-posed) and well-conditioned (ill-conditioned) problem?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem):

> Even if a problem is well-posed, it may still be ill-conditioned, meaning that a small error in the initial data can result in much larger errors in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be explained in a good way by looking at an example.

> Find roots of a polynomial

is well-posed.

However, for *some* polynomials, **a very small coefficient perturbation can affect the roots dramatically**, meaning lets say a root changes tens orders of magnitude more than coefficient change. This is actually (for many people) one of the most surprising results in mathematics. Most of the time, this will not be the case, however this still poses a difficult problem in numerical analysis.

Following example is from [a Matlab blog post called "Wilkinson’s Polynomials"](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/03/04/wilkinsons-polynomials/)

Observe this polynomial

$$ w(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{20} (x - i) = (x-1)(x-2) \ldots (x-20)$$

It has roots $1, 2, \dots, 20$.

Now observe this family of polynomials

$$ w(x) - \alpha x^{19}, \alpha = \pm 2^{-k}, k=23, 24, \dots, 36 $$

The behavior of roots is illustrated in this picture (red is for negative coefficient perturbation, black for positive)

[image]

A summary and further info on this topic can be found [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Wilkinson.pdf).

Comment: Is that right then :
In order to keep the problem well-posed, the perturbated output  (the root in your exemple) still need to change continously with the initial condition.
But ill-conditioned is just a subjective classification on how big the ouput change ? There is not defined threshold ? Thanks for the useful exemple

Comment: That's correct, continuous change of the output is necessary for well-posedness.

Comment: "The exact cutoff between well- and ill-conditioned depends on the context of the problem and the uses of the results." is the best I could find in references @Rafnuss

Comment: @VividD I'm curious about your comment: "This is actually (for many people) one of the most surprising results in mathematics."  Where did you get this information?

Answer (score 6):

According to the book [Numerical Analysis in Modern Scientific Computing: An Introduction](https://books.google.ch/books?id=1wjQE4wlR40C&redir_esc=y), 2nd edition, by Andreas Hohmann and Peter Deuflhard, second chapter on "Error Analysis":

> **Definition 2.2**
>
> The ***absolute** norm-wise condition number* of the problem $(f, x)$ is the smallest number $K_{abs} \geq 0$, such that
>
> $$|f(\tilde{x}) - f(x)| \dot{\leq} K_{abs} \cdot |\tilde{x} - x|, \text{ for $\tilde{x} \mapsto x$}$$
>
> *The problem $(f, x)$ is said to be **ill-posed** whenever such a number ($K_{abs}$) does not exist, which is formally equivalent to $K_{abs} = \infty$*.
>
> Analogously, the ***relative** norm-wise condition number* of $(f, x)$ is the smallest number $K_{rel} \geq 0$, such that
>
> $$\frac{|f(\tilde{x}) - f(x)|}{|f(x)|} \dot{\leq} K_{rel} \cdot \frac{|\tilde{x} - x|}{|x|}, \text{ for $\tilde{x} \mapsto x$}$$
>
> Thus $K_{abs}$ and $K_{rel}$ describe the increase of the absolute and the relative errors, respectively.
>
> *A problem $(f, x)$ is said to be **well-conditioned** when its condition number is small and **ill-conditioned** when its large. Naturally, the meaning of "small" and "large" has to be considered separately for each problem*.

Comment: I think your answer is more complete and more clear. That being said, I want to add that the definition on Trefethen's Numerical Linear Algebra looks even better (in my opinion). He defines $$K_{abs} = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{\tilde{x} \leq \delta} \frac{|f(\tilde{x}) - f(x) |}{| \tilde{x} - x |}.$$

I think this is a better definition because we define $K_{abs}$ with an equality, instead with an implicit definition. Also the idea of taking the $\sup$ match nicely with actually applications, where you just know a bound $\delta > 0$ for the perturbations $\tilde{x}$.