# What is the difference between ill-conditioned and ill-posed?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

I have a question regarding these two terms. I undertand that for a problem to be well-posed, it needs to satisfy three conditions:

1. Existence of solution
2. Unique solution
3. Solution depends with continuity on the data (i.e. small perturbations of the data lead to small perturbations in the solution). I will refer to this as stability.

Then, once we have our well-posed problem, we can define whether it is well- or ill-conditioned, which as stability, also measures how much the solution changes with perturbations in the data.

Then, I am confused. **Why are not all ill-conditioned problems ill-posed?**

As an example, say we have to solve for x in a nonlinear continuous function, so our problem is $f(x)=0$. Then, if I found the condition number to tend to infinity, **how could my problem ever be well-posed?** My professor used this example in class and I was just mind struck.

Note: I have already gone through the post [Well-posed vs Well-conditioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272630/well-posed-vs-well-conditioned), which asks a slightly different question and has helped me a lot, but I still have a lot of confusion in me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are still confused about in light of [the non-accepted answer at the question you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1917951/26369)? I don't work with numerical methods, but it seems like it could answer your question, so clarifying why it doesn't would help people respond.

Comment: Yes, well, from that answer,  what I got was that: if the condition number does not exist, we have an ill-posed problem; but if it exists, it can either be small (well-conditioned) or very large (ill-conditioned). This does not match to what my Professor explained, considering he said that an ill-conditioned problem can be well-posed or ill-posed. I just want to know how to tell whether my problem is well or ill-posed.

Comment: as far as I can tell from that answer, ill-posed corresponds to condition number $\infty$, which is certainly large. So an ill-conditioned problem would be well-posed when the number is large and finite, and ill-posed when it's infinite.

Comment: Okay, that is the exact same interpretation I got from the answer. I hope it is right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see a *problem* as a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ from a space of data $X$ to a solution space, $Y$. When solving a problem, we typically only concern ourselves with a solution at a particular data point $x \in X$. This combination of problem and data can be called a *problem instance*. The behavior of the problem may vary greatly from one instance to another.

Consider as an example solving the inverse problem $Ax = b$ where $A$ is **not** degenerate. So, $A$ is invertible and this is a well-posed problem. If we perturb the input a little bit

$$
A(x+\delta x) = b + \delta b
$$

we get

$$
\begin{align}
A\delta x &= \delta b\\
\implies \delta x &= A^{-1}\delta b\\
\implies \|\delta x\| &\le \|A^{-1}\|\|\delta b\|
\end{align}
$$

We also have

$$
\|A\|\|x\| \ge \|b\|
$$

Then the relative condition number of our problem is estimated by

$$
\frac{\|\delta x\|}{\|x\|} \le \|A\|\|A^{-1}\|\frac{\|\delta b\|}{\|b\|}
$$

But consider as a particular instance, the $n \times n$ matrix

$$
A = \left(\begin{matrix}1&\alpha&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1&\alpha&\cdots&0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
0&0 & 0& 1& \alpha\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

For large $n$ and $|\alpha| > 1$, this matrix is ill-conditioned since the inverse matrix contains $\alpha^{n-1}$ terms.  So, systems with "bad" matrices can be considered practically unstable, although formally the problem is well-posed and the stability condition $\|A^{−1}\| \lt \infty \|$ holds.